# Function adds an element to list every time someone opens a form

Tags: list, javascript, form, nintex

I have a form in which a user chooses "Standard", "CAD" or "Manager" which will add an element to a list automatically.

[image: Choice]

The function `onChangeMassnahmen()` will check if the checkbox is checked:

```
function onChangeMassnahmen(){
    var curvalue = NWF$("#" + varMassnahmen).find("input:checked").val();

    if (curvalue == "Ja") {
        NWF$(".cssMassnahmenType").hide();
    } else if (curvalue === "") {
        NWF$(".cssMassnahmenType").hide();
    } else{
        NWF$(".cssMassnahmenType").show();
    }
}
```

In my `onLoadForm()` which starts after a `NWF$(document).ready(function()` I have the following codepart:

```
NWF$("#" + varCataloguePicker).change(onChangeEquipment);
onChangeEquipment();
```

The `onChangeEquipment()` function will add an element to a list depending on whether "Standard", "CAD" or "Manager" has been checked :

```
function onChangeEquipment(){
    var curvalue = NWF$("#" + varCataloguePicker).find("input:checked").val();

    if (curvalue == "Standard"){
        fillStandard1();
        fillStandard2();

    } else if (curvalue == "CAD"){
        fillCAD();

    } else if (curvalue == "Manager"){
        fillManager();

    } else {
        console.log("Else");
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that since `onChanceEquipment()` is in the `onLoadForm()` **it will add an element to a list every time the form opens**. I want it to add an element to a list once, and not every time the form opens. It's not a bug, it's a logical mistake, but I don't know how to solve it. Tried working with booleans, but the values reset after a page refresh. Does someone know how one can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find that pretty much all bugs *are* logical mistakes. :)

You say you have the following lines of code in your `onFormLoad()` function, which runs when the the page loads:

```
// this line attaches your onChangeEquipment function
// as the change handler for the radio buttons control
NWF$("#" + varCataloguePicker).change(onChangeEquipment);

// this line immediately invokes that function,
// as if someone just changed the value of the radio buttons
onChangeEquipment();
```

Why do you have that second line?  Always invoking a function that adds an element to a list inside a function that runs on every page load will lead to exactly what you are seeing - that an element gets added to a list on every page load.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!